# How to integrate Janrain on android phone?

Tags: android, authentication, openid, integration, janrain

i' trying to find how to integrate janrain to my android app.....

i found that janrain for iphone is given in the janrain engage section but i couldnt find for android applicaion.

if anyone knows wer to find it , please leave a link ......

and also some documentation would help...

Thank you,,

Comment: Hi,

The Janrain development team is actively working on a native Android SDK similar to the one they already released for the iPhone and iPad.  If you are interested in being an early adopter and want to be considered for the beta program shoot me an email at android-beta(at)janrain . com.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the engage SDK on [github](http://github.com/janrain/engage.android/downloads) and find all instructions for setting up your application [here](https://rpxnow.com/docs/android).

Answer (score 0):

Android beta signup is now available in your Janrain dashboard at rpxnow.com
Registering for the beta will give you access to Android documentation in the dashboard.